# How to change height of react-navigation header

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

On attempt to stylize the header still can't change the height that is on the header

Even using

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    title: 'Title',
    headerStyle: {height: 60}
  })
```

[image]

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#adjusting-header-styles

Comment: did not work ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to remove entirely the header, and then I used a header from react-native-elements:

```
createStackNavigator(screens, { headerMode: 'none' })
```

And then, the Header

```
import { Header } from 'react-native-elements';

<Header...>
```

That component consider the top status bar size, and do all things automatically, and run on Expo and ejected apps

Comment: @Danks and have support to icons... tons of icons

Comment: `Joao Polo`, is there a way to change height of Header in react-native-elements?